# char занимает 1 байт?

Tags: c++

int занимает 4 байта, char - 1 байт. Почему тогда в самом низу программы выводится 12, а не 9?

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    ~A() {}
    void f_a();
private:
    int var_a;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() {}
    ~B() {}
    void f_b();
private:
    int var_b;
};

class C : public B
{
public:
    C() {}
    ~C() {}
    void f_c();
private:
    char var_c;
};

int main()
{
    A objA;
    B objB;
    C objC;

    cout << sizeof(objA) << endl; // выводит 4
    cout << sizeof(objB) << endl; // выводит 8
    cout << sizeof(objC) << endl; // выводит 12??? почему ни 9?

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы можно было создавать массивы объектов, и при этом чтобы каждый объект в массиве был выравнен согласно соответствующему значению, память, занимаемая объектами может быть дополнена таким образом, чтобы следующий за данным объект располагался по корректному выравненному адресу.

Это позволяет корректно использовать арифметику указателей, так как увеличение указателя на единицу увеличивает его значение на `sizeof( тип объекта )`.

В вашем случае объекты класса `C` выравниваются на границу, соответствующему типу `int`, и поэтому в конец объекта добавляется 3 байта, чтобы получить кратное `sizeof( int )`..

Если ваш компилятор поддерживает ключевое слово `alignof` , то вы можете получить значение, по которому выравнивается адрес памяти для объектов ваших классов. Так предложение

```
std::cout << alignof( C ) << std::endl;
```

выводит на консоль значение

```
4
```

которое соответствует значению `sizeof( int )`. То есть объекта класса `C` размещаются на по границе целых чисел. Чтобы это обеспечить, каждый объект дополняется 3 байтами.

Comment: В целом - да, но вот при чём тут массивы?

Comment: А, всё. Я перечитал код. Что-то я сначала вопрос не так понял.

Comment: @Qwertiy Потому что правильно расположить один объект не составляет проблем.

Comment: Если для класса B тип переменной изменить на `double`, то на выводе будут результаты 4, 16, 24. То есть сначала создается массив типа `int` для объекта класса A, а затем компилятор увидит, что следующий класс содержит переменную типа `double`, после чего он создаст массив объектов типа` double`, скопирует туда значение объект класса А, затем переместит объект класса B и объекат класса С? Все правильно понял?

Comment: @dmitrykozyr  Никакие массивы не создаются. В классе A член класса с типом int должен быть выравнен на границу для типа int. Так как класс B имеет объект типа double, то он должен быть выравнен на границу для типов double. Так как double обычно занимает 8 байтов, то происходит выравнивание объектов класса B до этого значения.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял